# How to plot categorical variables on x axis vs a numerical variable? Looking to make an area plot

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib

I want to make an area plot in seaborn or matplotlib using an index of categorical variables.  I have tried  a few things but I can't seem to get it.  Here's an image of my dataframe.  Thanks for any help.
[image]

Here's some examples of what I've tried.

```
plt.plot(areaData.index.values,areaData['Badassery'], data=areaData)
plt.plot(areaData['Badassery'])
```

I'm not really sure what else I should be doing.  Usually I get errors like "Series objects are mutable, and thus can't be hashed" or a blank chart.

Answer (score 0):

It appears that your categorical variable is set as the index, you want to reset it so that you can use it as a column.

```
#reset the index
areaData.reset_index()
areaData.plot.area(y='Badassery')
```

Refer to the documentation on [area](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.plot.area.html) plots with pandas.